# Split row into multiple rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a single column 'data' which contains words separated by space. I want to separate the data into multiple rows split by space. 
I have tried the following code but does not work:

```
from itertools import chain
def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split('\s+')))  
lengths = df['data'].str.split('\s+').map(len)
df_m = pd.DataFrame({"data" : np.repeat(df["data"], lengths)})
```

Dataframe example

```
words = ["a b c d e","b m g f e","c" ,"w"]
dff = pd.DataFrame({"data" :words })


data
0   a b c d e
1   b m g f e
2   c
3   w
```

Comment: can you post a sample dataframe for people to tinker with?

Comment: I just did it. Please take a look

Comment: thanks. what do you want the final DataFrame to look like? `dff` is not what you want?

Comment: dff is my current data frame, all data in each rows should be splited by space. There is coma in the example. but it should be space. I am correcting it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['text'] = ['word1 word2 word3', 'hey there hello word', 'stackoverflow is amazing']
```

Input:

```
                       text
0         word1 word2 word3
1      hey there hello word
2  stackoverflow is amazing
```

Do:

```
x = df.data.str.split(expand=True).stack().values
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df['words'] = x.tolist()
```

Output:

```
           words
0          word1
1          word2
2          word3
3            hey
4          there
5          hello
6           word
7  stackoverflow
8             is
9        amazing
```

Comment: Haha, thanks buddy! Feel free to post other solutions though, always good to know other workarounds :)

Comment: Thanks , that was it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Below is my attempt.

```
words = ['oneword','word1 word2 word3', 'hey there hello word', 'stackoverflow is amazing']
# make list of list and flatten.
flat_list = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist.split(' ')]
# put flat_list into DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({"data" :flat_list })
print(df)
```

```
             data
0         oneword
1           word1
2           word2
3           word3
4             hey
5           there
6           hello
7            word
8   stackoverflow
9              is
10        amazing
```